Exclude keys from Vue readonly object protection
I can make the object passed to the Vue 3 readonly() function read-only. Is there a way to make the object read-only except for the obj.target key or other specified keys?
import { reactive, readonly } from 'vue'

const obj = reactive({
  name: 'example',
  target: 'DOM',
})

const readonlyObj = readonly(obj)
readonlyObj.target = 'Modal' // not writable by default

Is there a way to allow editing of certain keys (as target) in a readonly object or not?

no.  readonly() is not that advanced and provides no options for anything other than returning deep readonly copy of the original.  the copy is reactive though, so to change readonlyObj.target you can change obj.value.target

This means that the object needs to be composed in a way that makes it possible to modified the original writable property through obj.target.
If it's impractical to keep a reference to the whole obj for some reason, there needs to be a reference to target at least, e.g.:
// Private
const obj = reactive({
  name: 'example',
  target: 'DOM',
})

// Public
const readonlyObj = readonly(obj)
const targetRef = toRef(obj , 'target')
targetRef.value = 'Modal'

Otherwise a completely new alternative to readonly needs to be created. E.g. a high-level approach that is limited to existing keys, similarly to reactivity requirements in Vue 2:
const semiReadonly(obj, readonlyKeys) {
  let newObj = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (readonlyKeys.includes(key))
      newObj[key] = computed(() => obj[key]);
    else
      newObj[key] = computed({
        get(key) {
          return obj[key];
        },
        set(key, val) {
          obj[key] = val;
        }
      });
  }
  
  return reactive(newObj);
}

In order to support changing set of keys it would require a watcher, or be implemented with low-level approach that uses Proxy.

Indeed, if I modify the original object, the readonly reactively tracks the changes. This would only be an issue if I no longer had access to the original object. Although I could pass the targetRef in a separate as you do; however personally, I need a solution where individual keys can be directly modified in the created readonly object. Nonetheless, I greatly appreciate your example, and it could be useful for others!

I don't think it's practical to change the way the framework work for the exotic requirements. But you'd need to implement custom reactive object similarly to reactive() and readonly() but suitable to your case. Totally new one through new Proxy (check vueuse toReactive, etc for some ideas). Or a synthetic one that will be synced with original object with a watcher, readonly properties can be wrapped with computeds. The second one would be more high-level but less efficient. It's unknown if the properties can be added after object creation, this would affect the complexity of a solution.

I updated the post with the example of an approach

You could make the opposite - make some props readonly:
const obj = reactive({
  get name() { return 'example' }, // readonly
  target: 'DOM',
})

Or even use reactive classes (could be non-anonymous too):
const obj = new class {
  constructor(){ return reactive(this); }
  get name() { return 'example' } // readonly
  target = 'DOM';
}

Another option is use a proxy to control the access:
Playground
class MyClass {
  static writableProps = new Set(['target']);
  constructor(){ 
    return new Proxy(reactive(this), {
      set(_, prop){
        if(MyClass.writableProps.has(prop)){
          return Reflect.set(...arguments);
        }
        // you can return false silently also
        throw new Error(`Property ${prop} is readonly!`);
      }
    });
  }
  name = 'example';
  target = 'DOM';
}

const obj = new MyClass;

You can make a utility:
Playground
import {reactive} from 'vue';
export function customReactive(writablePropsArray, obj = null){
  const writableProps = new Set(writablePropsArray);
  const make = obj =>  new Proxy(reactive(obj), {
      set(_, prop){
        if(writableProps.has(prop)){
          return Reflect.set(...arguments);
        }
        // you can return false silently also
        throw new Error(`Property ${prop} is readonly!`);
      }
    });
  if(obj) return make(obj);
  return make;
}


Your first solution is a bit complicated, as I would like to set most of my parameters to readonly, but it would work, it would just be tedious to declare every readonly value. I find your second solution appealing, and the customReactive function you created from it seems very useful. Thanks!
